# Funcionamiento del operador is

Tags: python, python-3.7, operador

¿Alguien sabe cómo funciona este operador is y por qué da estos resultados tan raros?

```
b = "cachorro"
d = "cachorro"
d is b
True

2*100 is 2*100
True

2*100 is 100*2
True

j=[1,2,3]
m=[1,2,3]
j is m
False
```

¿Qué rayos sucede ahí dentro?

Answer (score 3):

Para entender el operador `is` hay que entender algunos conceptos muy básicos de Python primero:

- Todo en Python es un objeto en memoria, desde un módulo, una función, una clase, un entero, etc todo son objetos en memoria.
- Una variable no es más que un nombre que está asociado a una referencia a un objeto en memoria, ni más ni menos. No tiene tipo, el tipo pertenece al objeto (clase de la que es instancia). Por lo tanto, podemos reasignar en cualquier momento otro objeto a la variable sin problemas.
- Como las variables no son más que nombres asociados a referencias, podemos tener muchas variables haciendo referencia al mismo objeto.

### ¿Cómo podemos saber si dos variables están asociadas al mismo objeto en memoria?

Aquí es donde entra el operador `is`, conocido como **operador de identidad**, permite comprobar si dos variables, dos nombres, están asociados al mismo objeto. **Retorna `True` solo y solo si sus operandos apuntan al mismo objeto**.

Hay tendencia a confundirlo con el operador de igualdad (`==`), pero son cosas muy distintas y usarlos inadecuadamente llevan a errores. El operador de igualdad retorna `True` si dos objetos son considerados iguales, en el caso de secuencias como una cadena, dos cadenas son iguales si tienen los mismo caracteres y en el mismo orden.

Dos cadenas pueden ser iguales (`==`) pero no ser el mismo objeto (`is`). Obviamente, lo contrario no puede ocurrir.

Tu duda viene ahora con:

```
b = "cachorro"
d = "cachorro"
d is b 
True
```

¿Por qué? Si en teoría son dos objetos distintos... Pues no, no lo son. No es que `is` sea estúpido, es que el intérprete lleva a cabo algunas optimizaciones bajo bambalinas que no te cuenta, entre ellas mantiene referencias a enteros pequeños (generalmente entre -5 y 256) y literales cadenas (ambos inmutables) en memoria de forma permanente, haciendo que solo exista un objeto en toda la ejecución.

De esta forma, se evita tener que crear nuevos objetos cada vez que se usa un literal para `1` por ejemplo, reusa la instancia que ya tiene.

Esta optimización solo tiene sentido con objetos pequeños y que son estadísticamente usados repetidamente en un mismo programa y que son inmutables. El resto son eliminados por el GC en cuanto el contador de referencias llega a 0, o estariamos usando memoria solo "por si" se intenta instanciar un objeto igual en el futuro.

Eso si, CPython solo garantiza que van a ser singletons siempre:

- `None`
- `False`
- `True`

es decir, sabemos seguro que en un intérprete solo va a existir un objeto `None`, uno `True` y otro `False`. El resto son optimizaciones que hace el intérprete cuando y cómo le parece y que no podemos dar por sentadas nunca, realmente son detalles de implementación, no características del lenguaje.

Esta es la razón por la que no es correcto hacer:

```
if foo == None
```

sino:

```
if foo is None
```

es más eficiente, además de saber con total seguridad que cualquier referencia a `None` apunta al mismo objeto siempre.

En el caso de los literales es una optimización muy obvia, imagina que tenemos algo como:

```
a = "Hola"
b = "Hola"
c = "Hola"
```

cuando el intérprete lee el script y va a generar el bytecode y ejecutarlo podría ser estúpido y crear tres objetos `str` en memoria idénticos, con el gasto de recursos que conlleva. Tiene sentido, dado que `str` es inmutable, crear un solo objeto `str` y darle a cada variable una referencia al mismo...

Para comprobar esto puedes hacer uso del builtin `id` que retorna la identificación única de cada objeto en memoria, indirectamente su dirección de memoria.

```
>>> b = "cachorro"
>>> c = "cachorro"
>>> b is c
True
>>> id(b)
139804507263728
>>> id(c)
139804507263728

>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
139804507277248
>>> id(b)
139804507277120

>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
>>> True
>>> id(a)
139804513250816
>>> id(b)
139804513250816
```

Observa que `b = a` no crea otro objeto, esto solo hace que se mire el objeto al que a apunta `a`, se cree una nueva referencia al mismo y esa referencia se asocia al nombre `b`. Ahora el objeto `list` en memoria tiene dos referencias asociadas. Si después hacemos `a = 1`, el objeto `list` se queda solo con una referencia, si hacemos de nuevo `b = 3` el objeto `list` se queda sin referencias y el recolector de basura lo manda a mejor vida liberando la memoria que ocupaba.

Por otro lado, observa que pasa con enteros grandes:

```
>>> a = 125456585696648115
>>> b = 125456585696648115
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
139804507423184
>>> id(b)
139804507423600
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que es mucho más eficiente comprobar si dos nombres apuntan al mismo objeto (`a is b`) que comprobar la igualdad (`a == b`). En el caso de una cadena hay que recorrer ambas y comprobar carácter por carácter que son iguales. Ahora bien, solo debemos sustituir `==` por `is` en aquellos casos en lo que el singlenton está garantizado. `is` no comprueba igualdad su uso es comprobar identidad (obviamente si dos variables apuntan al mismo objeto su "valor" es igual...), solo en casos de singletons garantizados podemos usarlos como substituto del operador de igualdad con seguridad.

Comment: otro ejemplo donde fallaria `a = 2000` y `b = 2000` si usamos `a is b` eso dara como resultado `False`

Comment: Efectivamente, he puesto el ejemplo con 125456585696648115 pero realmente cualquier entero por encima de 256 no es incluido en la psicina (y aún así es un detalle de implementación, nadie te asegura que en un futuro se incluya hasta el 1000 o que se mantengan solo hasta el 9 sin avisar)