# Insertar nodos en lista enlazada simple ordenada (SortedLinkedList)

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Buenos días quiero implementar en la clase SortedLinkedList un método que admita como parámetro un valor a insertar en la lista. El valor se insertará en orden, de forma que se inserte, después de todos los que sean menores y justo antes de los que sean mayores o iguales. La lista permanecerá ordenada de menor a mayor en todo momento.

Este primer módulo genera la lista, por tanto en el método que quiero implementar no tengo que crear ninguna lista

```
import random

from sortedlinkedlist import SortedLinkedList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_slist = SortedLinkedList()

    for i in range(10):
        my_slist.insert(random.randint(10, 100))

    for item in my_slist:
        print(item)
```

En este segundo módulo se encuentra una serie de métodos qe tratan las listas encadenadas y no deben ser modificados porque he comprobado que funcionan

```
class SortedLinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
            self.value = value
            self.next_node = next_node

    def __init__(self):
        self.__first = None
        self.__len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__current = self.__first
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__current != None:
            result = self.__current.value
            self.__current = self.__current.next_node
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

A continuación va el método que quiero implementar. Esto es lo que he intentado

```
def insert(self, value):
        if value == 0:
            self.insert_as_first(value)
        elif value == len(self):
            self.append(value)
        elif value < 0 or value > len(self):
            raise IndexError
        else:
            current = self.__first
            current_pos = 1

            while current_pos < value:
                current = current.next_node
                current_pos += 1

            current.next_node = self.Node(value, current.next_node)
            self.__len += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando vas a insertar un nuevo nodo en la lista podemos tener una de estas situaciones:

### ♦ La lista está vacía

Por lo tanto `self.__first` es `None` y `self.__len` es `0`. En este caso simplemente tenemos que crear una nueva instancia de `Node` y asignarlo a `self.__first`.

### ♦ El valor a ingresar es menor que el valor del primer nodo de la lista

En este caso nuestro nuevo nodo debe pasar a ser el primero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello hacemos:

1. Instanciamos un nuevo `Nodo` y le asignamos a su atributo `next_node` el nodo asociado a `self.__first` hasta ahora, el que era el primer nodo de la lista.
2. Después reasignamos a  `self.__first` nuestro nuevo nodo para que pase a ser el primero.

### ♦ Nada de lo anterior ocurre

En este caso el nodo debe ser insertado entre otros nodos o al final de la lista. Por tanto debemos iterar sobre la misma hasta encontrar la posición en la que nuestro nuevo nodo quedaría ordenado:

- Si encontramos un nodo con valor menor al que queremos agregar pero cuyo siguiente nodo tiene un valor superior o igual, debemos insertar el nuevo nodo entre ambos.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  Esto se haría en dos pasos:

  1. Asignamos al atributo `next_node` de nuestro nuevo nodo el nodo siguiente al que estamos en ésta iteración (el primero nodo de la lista cuyo valor es mayor o igual al valor de nuestro nodo  nuevo)
  2. Reasignamos al atributo `next_node` del nodo actual de la iteración, el último cuyo valor es menor a nuestro nuevo nodo, la instancia del nodo recién creado.
- Si llegamos a un nodo en el que el nodo que le sigue es `None` (último nodo de la lista) solo tenemos que asignarle al atributo `next_node` de éste nodo nuestro nuevo nodo, que pasará a ser el último.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu método podría quedar algo así:

```
def insert(self, value):
    item = self.Node(value)

    if self.__first is None:
        self.__first = item

    elif self.__first.value > value:
        self.__first, item.next_node = item, self.__first

    else:
        current_node = self.__first
        while True:
            if current_node.next_node is None:
                current_node.next_node = item
                break
            elif current_node.next_node.value >= value:
                item.next_node = current_node.next_node
                current_node.next_node = item
                break
            current_node = current_node.next_node
    self.__len += 1
```

Otra posibilidad es usar un `for in - else`  con `range` aprovechando que nuestra lista implementa `len`:

```
def insert(self, value):
    item = self.Node(value)

    if self.__first is None:
        self.__first = item

    elif self.__first.value > value:
        self.__first, item.next_node = item, self.__first

    else:
        current_node = self.__first
        for _ in range(self.__len - 1):
            if current_node.next_node.value >= value:
                item.next_node = current_node.next_node
                current_node.next_node = item
                break
            current_node = current_node.next_node
        else:
            current_node.next_node = item
    self.__len += 1
```

Al evitar dos comparaciones la inserción es algo más eficiente.

No uses los operadores de igualdad/desigualdad (`==`/`!=`) para saber si una variable está asociada a `None`, None es un singleton, la forma correcta es usar el operador de identidad (`is`/`is not`):

- [Funcionamiento del operador is](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/343143/15089)

Comment: Tenía un pequeño problema con el código. He realizado pruebas para dicho bloque de código y obtengo los siguientes fallos. Si trato de insertar un elemento menor que los existentes obtengo que: 

La longitud de lista resultante es incorrecta: 7
Se esperaba: 6. Asi mismo, obtengo esta otra excepción si trato de Insertar un elemento en una lista vacía.

La longitud de lista resultante es incorrecta: 2
Se esperaba: 1

Comment: Hola @LearningDeveloper, tenía un "pequeño" error al sumar a `__len`, en su momento modifiqué el código  sacando el incremento de los condicionales, pero se me pasó eliminar la línea de los dos primeros (if y else) lo que hacía que se incrementara en dos  si el item a  insertar es el menor o no existen items en la lista. Corregido, gracias por el aviso y perdón por el despiste :(

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente por su tiempo y ayuda. El código pasa todos los test. No me había percatado de ese despiste y pensé que era fallo de los test o algo. Muchas gracias por todo y no pasa nada por el despiste, faltaría más :)