# ¿Cómo saber si los elementos de una lista son iguales?

Tags: python

```
    def hay_elementos_iguales(lista: list)->bool:
     elementos_iguales=False
     longitud=len(lista)-1
     contador_de_comparacion=0
     while contador_de_comparacion<longitud and elementos_iguales==False:
         if lista[contador_de_comparacion]==lista[longitud]:
             elementos_iguales=True    
         contador_de_comparacion+=1
     return elementos_iguales
```

Este es el código que tenía pensado para hacer la comparación, el problema es que de algún modo solo arroja True cuando el primer y ultimo valor de la lista son iguales. Estuve revisando otras respuestas de usuarios en la comunidad a una pregunta similar pero para la solución que ideaban es mediante el método set e index mientras que yo debo generar esta solución valiéndome solo de ciclos while y for.

Answer (score 1):

Con un solo ciclo no vas a poder hacer ésto a no ser que la lista estuviera ordenada previamente. La idea sería usar dos ciclos anidados, uno va recorriendo la lista desde el primer elemento hasta el último y otro anidado dentro recorre desde el elemento siguiente del que está el primer ciclo hasta el final, solo queda comparar si ese ítem tiene alguno delante igual:

```
def hay_elementos_iguales(lista: list) -> bool:
    longitud = len(lista)
    for i in range(longitud):
        item = lista[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, longitud):
            if item == lista[j]:
                return True
    return False
```

Si te dejan usar `enumerate`, esto es algo más eficiente:

```
def hay_elementos_iguales(lista: list) -> bool:
    for i, item in enumerate(lista):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
            if item == lista[j]:
                return True
    return False
```

> ```
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([1, 3, 1, 0])
> True
>
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([1, 3, 5, 0])
> False
>
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([1, 3, 5, 0, 0])
> True
>
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([1, 3, 5, 0, 5])
> True
>
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([1])
> False
>
> >>> hay_elementos_iguales([])
> False
> ```

La forma eficiente de hacer esto si estamos en una situación real es usar conjuntos como tu mismo referías en la pregunta:

```
def hay_elementos_iguales(lista: list) -> bool:
    return len(lista) != len(set(lista))
```

Un apunte, no hagas:

```
if variable == True

if variable  == False:

while variable == True

...
```

Como norma general, cuando quieres comprobar si una variable se evalúa como cierta o no debes hacer:

```
if variable:

if not vaiable:

while variable:

while not variable:

....
```

Si quieres saber si la variable es específicamente un boleano y no si se evalúa como cierta solo debes usar el operador `is`:

```
if variable is True:

if variable is not True:
```

- [Funcionamiento del operador is](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/343143/funcionamiento-del-operador-is/343149#343149)

Comment: No había pensado en el uso de ciclos anidados, es una excelente solución, gracias por tu perspectiva y consejos para trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque tu función se llama `hay_elementos_iguales()`, lo que parece sugerir que busca si contiene *al menos* dos elementos iguales, el título de la pregunta es en cambio "¿Cómo saber si los elementos de una lista son iguales?", que parece más bien sugerir que *todos* los elementos de la lista han de ser iguales.

Si la pregunta era la primera (al menos dos iguales) necesitas bucles anidados como FJSevilla te ha respondido.

Pero me inclino más a pensar que se trata de la segunda (que todos los elementos sean iguales), especialmente a la vista de tu función en la que comparas todos los elementos con el último. Supongo que tu lógica es: "si todos los elementos son iguales al último, es que son iguales entre sí".

Pero tu implementación tiene un fallo de lógica. Comienzas suponiendo que no son iguales (`elementos_iguales=False`) pero tan pronto como encuentras uno igual al último haces esa variable `True`. Por tanto si el primer elemento es igual al último ya no mira más.

El problema se arregla "dando la vuelta" a la lógica. Comienzas suponiendo que todos son iguales, y tan pronto como encuentres uno que no lo es, ya puedes retornar  `False`. Sólo si terminas el bucle sin haber encontrado ninguno diferente, concluirás que puedes retornar `True`.

Es decir, sin apenas cambiar tu implementación:

```
def todos_elementos_iguales(lista: list)->bool:
  elementos_iguales=False
  longitud=len(lista)-1
  contador_de_comparacion=0
  while contador_de_comparacion<longitud and elementos_iguales==True:
     if lista[contador_de_comparacion] != lista[longitud]:
         elementos_iguales=False
     contador_de_comparacion+=1
 return elementos_iguales
```

Ahora bien, yo usaría una versión más "pythónica" en la que itero con un bucle `for` y comparo con el primero de la lista. De ese modo no necesito un contador de comparación ni el cálculo de cuántos elementos hay. Y ya de paso tampoco necesito la variable `elementos_iguales` pues puedo retornar directamente `True` o `False`:

```
def todos_elementos_iguales(lista: list)->bool:
  for dato in lista:
     if dato != lista[0]:
        return False
  return True
```

**Bonus**

Otra versión aún más breve (y hasta más legible) se consigue usando la función `all()` de python, que recibe un iterable y retorna `True` si todos los elementos del iterable son ciertos o `False` tan pronto como encuentre uno falso, junto con una *expresión generadora* que es un tipo de expresión que contiene la palabra `for` y que crea un iterable que se le puede pasar a `all()`.

Aunque entiendo por lo que mencionas en un comentario que no se te permite el uso de estas funciones "avanzadas", lo pongo aquí para que conozcas su existencia. Tal vez te sea útil en el futuro:

```
def todos_elementos_iguales(lista: list) -> bool:
  return all(dato == lista[0] for dato in lista)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu perspectiva también, mi pregunta iba más encaminada a la solución que me dio FJSevilla pero igual te agradezco por la información de la función all y del código que podría servirme para el futuro.