# Como se interpreta este código en PY estimados, ya que nunca habia visto este tipo de comparaciones en una sola linea

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este código como lo interpretan:

```
  def transición(self, estado, acción):
        robot, a, b = estado

        c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio" and acción is "nada" else 1

        return ((estado, c_local) if a is "nada" else
                (("A", a, b), c_local) if acción is "ir_A" else
                (("B", a, b), c_local) if acción is "ir_B" else
                ((robot, "limpio", b), c_local) if robot is "A" else
                ((robot, a, "limpio"), c_local))
```

Más que nada esta linea por favor:

```
c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio" and acción is "nada" else 1
```

No entiendo el c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, la línea sobre la que tienes dudas es incorrecta:

```
c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio" and acción is "nada" else 1
                                             ^^ 
                                             ^^
```

debe ser:

```
c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio" and acción == "nada" else 1
```

El operador de identidad comprueba si **dos identificadores apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria**, no si dos objetos son iguales. Solo se debe usar is como sinónimo de igualdad con los tres objetos singletons que C-Python asegura por implementación, `None`, `False` y `True`. Para el resto **jamás se debe usar `is` con ésta finalidad**, nada nos asegura que funcione como esperamos, son optimizaciones internas del interprete y son detalles de implementación. Asumir que el interprete va realizar dicha optimización y a tratar la cadena como singleton es jugar con fuego, puede que si, pero puede que no.

- [Funcionamiento del operador is](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/343143/15089)

Corregido eso, esa línea es lo que se conoce en Python como [expresiones condicionales](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), similar a la función del operador ternario en otros lenguajes. Python prima la legibilidad, tanto que si traducimos la línea al español queda bastante claro:

> `c_local` igual a `0` si (`a`, `b` y `"limpio"` son iguales) y (`acción` es igual a `"nada"`) en caso contrario `1`

```
a == b == "limpio"
```

equivale a algo como:

```
(a == b) and (b == "limpio")
```

En su conjunto, la expresión es equivalente a:

```
if (a == b == "limpio") and (acción == "nada"):
    c_local = 0
else:
    c_local = 1
```

Los paréntesis no son necesarios (el operador de igualdad tiene preferencia sobre `and`), son solo para dejar caro el orden de evaluación.

El `return` hace uso de la misma sintaxis, pero algo más compleja, tanto que en mi opinión sería mejor usar bloques condicionales normales en favor de la legibilidad. Ésto:

```
if a == "nada":
    return estado, c_local
elif acción == "ir_A":
    return ("A", a, b), c_local
elif acción == "ir_B":
    return ("B", a, b), c_local
elif robot == "A":
    return (robot, "limpio", b), c_local
else:
    return (robot, a, "limpio"), c_local
```

Comment: Buenas tardes estimado, es decir c_local = 0 if a == b == "limpio"  y el c_local a que se refiere con el = 0 le asigna ese valor si se cumple el if?

Comment: Exacto, si la condicón se cumple c_local será 0, si no será 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero por el apoyo, que tengas buenas tardes.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es la implementación del operador ternario en Python, más o menos.

Lo que dice es lo que se lee. Si `a` es igual a `b` y si son iguales a `limpio`, entonces se le asigna `0`, si no, se les asigna `1`