# ¿Por que tengo la salida None en mi Codigo?

Tags: python

Quisiera entender por que cuando ejecuto mi codigo me arroja la siguiente salida en consola:

8

9

20

None

Estuve haciendo debugg pero no encuentro la razón de porque imprime **None**
arroja None  al terminar de recorrer el **for** dentro de la función **area()**  en la clase **pruebarectangulo**.

```
class Rectangulo:
        def __init__(self, base, altura):
            self.base = base
            self.altura = altura
    
    
    
    class pruebaRectangulo:
        rectangulos = []
    
        def __init__(self, rectangulos=[]):
          self.rectangulos = rectangulos
    
        def agregar(self, r):
           self.rectangulos.append(r)
    
        def area(self):
            for r in self.rectangulos:
                salida = r.base*r.altura
                if(salida == None):
                    break
                print(salida)
    
    r = Rectangulo(2, 4)
    r2 = pruebaRectangulo([r])
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(3, 3))
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(4, 5))
    print(r2.area())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`None` viene de la línea `print(r2.area())`. Imprimes la salida del método de instancia `area`, pero dicho método retorna `None` siempre. No tiene ningún estamento `return` explícito. **Cuando se ejecuta un `return` de forma explícita todo objeto llamable en Python retorna `None` por defecto.**

Si quieres que retorne el área de cada retángulo (que es más apropiado que imprimir desde el método) debes usar `return` en vez de `print` y meterlos en una lista o usar un generador:

```
def areas(self):
    areas = []
    for r in self.rectangulos:
        salida = r.base * r.altura
        reas.append(salida)
    return salida
```

Si quieres imprimir desde el método, entonces:

```
def areas(self):
    for r in self.rectangulos:
        salida = r.base * r.altura
        print(salida)


r = Rectangulo(2, 4)
r2 = pruebaRectangulo([r])
r2.agregar(Rectangulo(3, 3))
r2.agregar(Rectangulo(4, 5))
r2.area() # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< sin print
```

No obstante una estructura más lógica sería que el cálculo del área se haga en la propia clase `Triangulo`:

```
class Rectangulo:
    def __init__(self, base, altura):
        self.base = base
        self.altura = altura
        
    def area(self):
        return self.base * self.altura    
    

class Rectangulos:
    def __init__(self, rectangulos=None):
      self.rectangulos = rectangulos if rectangulos is not None else []

    def agregar(self, rectangulo):
       self.rectangulos.append(rectangulo)

    def areas(self):
        return [rect.area() for rect in self.rectangulos]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = Rectangulo(2, 4)
    r2 = Rectangulos([r])
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(3, 3))
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(4, 5))
    print(r2.areas())
```

o si quieres imprimir las áreas una debajo de otra:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = Rectangulo(2, 4)
    r2 = Rectangulos([r])
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(3, 3))
    r2.agregar(Rectangulo(4, 5))
    for area in r2.areas():
        print(area)
```

Existen más alternativas, desde retornar un generador en vez de una lista a usar propiedades.

Tres observaciones:

- No se debe hacer `var == None`, `None` es un singleton, lo correcto es usar el operador de identidad is con él:

  ```
  var is None 
  var is not None
  ```

  - [Funcionamiento del operador is](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/343143/15089)
- Mucho cuidado con:

  ```
  def __init__(self, rectangulos=[]):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  **Los argumentos por defecto se evalúan en tiempo de definición**, todos los objetos de la clase que crees compartirán la misma lista por defecto, como una lista es un objeto mutable, ésto no es trivial:

  ```
  class Foo():
      def __init__(self, bar=[]):
          self.bar = bar
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> a = Foo()
  > >>> b = Foo()
  > >>> a.bar.append(4)
  > >>> a.bar
  > [4]
  > >>> b.bar
  > [4]
  > >>> b.bar.append(13)
  > >>> a.bar
  > [4, 13]
  > >>> c = Foo()
  > >>> c.bar
  > [4, 13]
  > ```

  En cambio, una forma correcta de inicializar para evitar ésto podía ser:

  ```
  class Foo():
      def __init__(self, bar=None):
          self.bar = bar if bar is not None else []
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> a = Foo()
  > >>> b = Foo()
  > >>> a.bar.append(4)
  > >>> b.bar
  > []
  > >>> a.bar
  > [4]
  > ```
- No se si en tu segunda clase verdaderamente quieres que `rectangulos` sea un atributo de clase y no de instancia, porque lo defines como tal. Si es así bien, pero si no ten en cuenta:

  - [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089)

  ---

  Si quieres que sea un atributo de case, la reasignación el el incializador crea un atributo de instancia que ensombrece al de clase, debería ser:

  ```
  class Rectangulos:
      rectangulos = []

      def __init__(self, rectangulos=None):
          if rectangulos is not None:
              type(self).rectangulos = rectangulos
  ```

  pero recuerda que todas las instancias de la clase comparten el mismo objeto y no creo que busques eso.